# Role relationship uses the wrong model_type in spatie/laravel

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-permission

I tried to list roles and check if a user has a particular role. The model type stored in table `model_has_roles` is `Modules\Admin\Entities\User` instead of the default `App\Models\User`. I use `users` relationship provided by spatie role. So here is the query in my controller:

```
$roles = Role::withCount([
               'users' => function ($query) use ($id){
                    return $query->where('model_id', $id)->limit(1);
                }
         ])
         ->orderBy('name')
         ->get();
```

As the result, the `users_count` always return 0 because the model_type is `App\Models\User` instead of `Modules\Admin\Entities\User`. How can I change the model_type to the one that should be? I was thinking that I need to extend the Role model but I don't know how to do it.